# Timeframe for entry

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration

My parents were granted a 5-year multiple tourist visa for the USA 3 years ago. They were unable to go to the US then, and now are planning to go this year. Is there any timeframe within which one must enter the USA after the visa is granted?

Answer (score 3):

They must enter before the expiration date of the visa if they wish to use it.